# php if statement if variable is empty or has at least 5 characters

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to check if my variable is not empty and has at least 5 characters. The $results is a mix of letters and numbers.

```
 if($results == !empty AND has 5 characters){
   //do a task
 } else {
   //do another task
 }
```

Comment: `empty()` and `strlen()`, now go find those on php.net

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

If a string is empty, it can't have a string length over 5, so this is the simplest way to solve your solution:

```
if ( strlen($result) > 5 ) {
   //do a task
} else {
   //do another task
}
```

See [`strlen()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function on php.net